Why Firestore on FLutter causing "reciever can be null" Error?
I watched the Tutorial from Google about Firestore, but i came up with problems about "null exception". I imported the package and all, but i dont get the answer.
Main Page
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("testCity").snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Text("Bitte Warten");
    }

    return ListView.separated(

      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 16, 24, 24),
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,

      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        return NormalCard(database: snapshot.data.docs[index]);
      },

      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
      => const Divider(
        height: 32,
        thickness: 4,
        color: Color(0xFF484848),
      ),
    );
  },
)

Normalcard Widget
class NormalCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const NormalCard({Key? key, required this.database}) : super(key: key);

  final DocumentSnapshot database;

  @override
  State<NormalCard> createState() => _NormalCardState();
}

class _NormalCardState extends State<NormalCard> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    DocumentSnapshot database = widget.database;

    return LayoutBuilder(
      ...
    );
  }
}

Following Errors occured:
at Problems Tab:
"The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'."
at run:
lib/Pages/page_startseite.dart:80:40: Error: Property 'docs' cannot be accessed on 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>?' because it is potentially null.

'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.14.0/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
Try accessing using ?. instead.
itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
^^^^
lib/Pages/page_startseite.dart:82:59: Error: Property 'docs' cannot be accessed on 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>?' because it is potentially null.
'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.14.0/lib/cloud_firestore.dart').
'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
Try accessing using ?. instead.
return NormalCard(database: snapshot.data.docs[index]);
^^^^
lib/Pages/page_exploreseite.dart:112:40: Error: Required named parameter 'database' must be provided.
return const NormalCard();
^
lib/Widgets/card_restaurantNormal.dart:5:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const NormalCard({Key? key, required this.database}) : super(key: key);
^^^^^^^^^^

If i try adding "?" the codeline interupts.
and if i add "!", it doesn't change anything.
Can anyone help me with this problems so i can implement my Database from Firestore as Backend of my Project?

You are not wrong, the error should definitely change when you write snapshot?.docs or snapshot!.docs. Are you sure you are saving after making the changes? Using !. should only be able to give you an error at runtime. Also, could you please include the relevant part of page_startseite.dart around like 80?

I wrote "!" but then the compiler can't run anymore, and says "database must be provided". page_startseite.dart Line 80 is the itemcount of the Listview.

The problem is here:
return NormalCard(database: snapshot.data.docs[index]);

Your snapshot is of type AsyncSnapshot and its data property is defined as:
T? data

The ? in there indicates that the data property may be null. So you either need to handle the null, for example by ensuring the compiler that it will never be null with:
return NormalCard(database: snapshot.data!.docs[index]);
//                                       


if i do so i get the Failure: lib/Pages/page_exploreseite.dart:112:40: Error: Required named parameter 'database' must be provided.
return const NormalCard();
^
lib/Widgets/card_restaurantNormal.dart:5:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const NormalCard({Key? key, required this.database}) : super(key: key);
^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\Users\nikol\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Your error message says you wrote "return const NormalCard();", which seems to be an error in another file. If you use an IDE such as Android Studio, in will show you the different errors more easily understandable. Otherwise, running your code often is the way to go, so you don't lose sight of what changes might cause an error.

Let us know if that helps.
